# unset proxy in atom using apm config

Tags: atom-editor

You can set proxy for atom using

```
apm config set http-proxy http://....
```

but how do you unset the proxy using apm config. I tried

```
apm config unset http-proxy
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
apm config delete <your-key>
```

Where `<your-key>` is your http-proxy, so become: *apm config delete http-proxy*

Then verify it using:

```
apm config get <key>
```

It should be set to null. Anyway you can explore the list of the command by:

```
apm help
```

and then

```
apm help <your-chosen-command>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the command would be, but you could always edit your `.apmrc` file directly. For me, it's located at `~\.atom\.apmrc`.